# Commenting on cells

Tags: excel, vba, comments

So I have some code that comments on cells based on information beside of it and it is working almost flawlessly. However, I am having an issue where it is working on all sheets in the entire workbook instead of just sheet 3 like it is supposed to. I have this code set up on sheet 3 only in the VBA projects. So my question is how would I make this work only on one single sheet?
Here is my code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.ClearComments

Dim targetRng As Range, commentSrcRng As Range
Dim strPrefix As String 'string Prefix

Set targetRng = Application.Range("D16,D18,D20,D22,D24,D26,D28,D30,D32,D34,D36,D38")
Set commentSrcRng = targetRng.Offset(0, 1)

Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Long
i = 1
    For Each cel In targetRng
        If cel <> "" Then
            cel.AddComment
                cel.Comment.Visible = False
                cel.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
                cel.Comment.Text strPrefix & commentSrcRng.Cells(i)
        End If
            i = i + 2
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I am having an issue where it is working on all sheets in the entire workbook

That's because you've coded it to work on the `ActiveSheet`

To refer to the sheet the event is coded in, use `Me`

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Me.UsedRange.ClearComments

    Dim targetRng As Range, commentSrcRng As Range
    Dim strPrefix As String 'string Prefix

    Set targetRng = Me.Range("D16,D18,D20,D22,D24,D26,D28,D30,D32,D34,D36,D38")
    Set commentSrcRng = targetRng.Offset(0, 1)

    Dim cel As Range
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    For Each cel In targetRng
        If cel <> "" Then
            cel.AddComment
            cel.Comment.Visible = False          cel.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
            cel.Comment.Text strPrefix & commentSrcRng.Cells(i)
        End If
        i = i + 2
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That fixed it. For future reference, Me. refers specifically to the sheet that I write the code on correct?